# How to implement like result after capture screen shot on IOS 11

Tags: ios11

On IOS 11 After capture screen shot..We will see a floating windows contain result image of screen show and it's can drag, move around screen and on top all app and all screen?

How can I custom a view ..which same result like image bellow

[image]